# C++ double char array deliminator

Tags: c++, c, character

I am trying to input a few first names into a double character array with the following code:

```
int main(void) 

char firstName[4][10];
Int num = 2;

for (int i=0; i<num; i++) 
  for (int j=0; j<10; j++) 
        cin >> firstName[i] [j] ;
        if(firstName[i] [j] == '.') 
            break;

Return(0);
```

Basically, I am looking for a simple, better way of inputting the names into a double char array without having to end the input with a period. If I try using the char delimiter. ' /0' it still attempts to fill in the first full row of the characters array before continuing.

Comment: I'm really missing those curly braces. Where are they? Did you ever try to compile your code?

Comment: Speaking of curly braces, if the posted code compiles, your compiler is obsolete.

Comment: I'm also missing keywords spelled with lowercase letter.  Sloppiness is not a virtue for programmers.

Comment: I didn't add the braces due to mobile device. I did compile and no issues with my syntax

Comment: @DavidK: Obsolete? Try "not a C++ compiler".

Comment: @user593301: This is simply not C or C++ code. I don't care what device you're on: post your _actual_ code! Perhaps wait until you get home and can use a real computer?

Comment: Apologize for misspelling. Syntax is correct. Please assume that

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: The question stills makes sense if that's considered to be pseudocode.... but it should have been described as such.

Comment: @user593301: One of your problems may be that `break` only exits from one loop.

Comment: I apologize. I should have mentioned that to be pseudocode

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: IIRC, in Visual C++ 6.0 the scope of a variable declared like `for (int i=...` did not end at the end of the `if` statement.  This was annoying for multiple reasons.  Come to think of it, this does not contradict your remark. :-)

Comment: @DavidK: Yes that's true but I'm more worried about the lack of braces and what is this `Return`? `Int`?

Comment: Lack of braces means the `if` is outside all of the loops.  It will compile only if the compiler thinks `i` and `j` are still in scope after the loop ends.  Actually, I suspect this wouldn't compile even in VC++6; the compiler would (wrongly) have said `i` was in scope but I think even VC++6 would realize `j` is not in scope there.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: I overlooked the `Return`. I suppose it's `return` misspelled. I think even VC++6 would choke on that.

Comment: Is this python? Why would you post pseudocode for a C++ question about your code failing to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the coding side, since this is C++, don't store lists of strings in a two-dimensional array of char.  Try `std::vector<std::string>` instead.  And don't read your file one character at a time; read larger blocks of characters.

If you can guarantee that there are never spaces embedded within first names, you can write something like `cin >> s;`, where `s` is of type `std::string`, to read a whole name in one operation.

If you may have blanks within a name, try reading an entire line of the file into an `std::string` and extract the data you need from there.  If that's too complicated, maybe you need to reconsider your input file's format.  (Maybe include a sample of an input file next time so we can see what you thought you were trying to read.)